# Javascript : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, addeventlistener

I have written a script that validates username submitted through form. If the user name is greater than 5 characters, it should show some message to the user. 
The error that I'm getting is

> :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at checkusername (eventobject.html:24)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (eventobject.html:18)

I have used 'blur' event.

the code is :

```
 <html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <label for="text">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <p id="para"></p>

  </form>

  <script>
    var el=document.getElementById("text");
    el.addEventListener('blur',function(){checkusername(5);},false);

    var msg=document.getElementById("para");

    function checkusername(min)
    {
     if(this.value.length<min)
     {
       msg.textContent="username less than 5 characters";
     }
     else
     {
      msg.textContent='';
     }
    }

  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

The above code works fine when I write the same event handler without parameters.
 the code for event handling without passing parameters is shown below:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <label for="text">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <p id="para"></p>

  </form>

  <script>
    var el=document.getElementById("text");

    el.addEventListener('blur',checkusername,false);

    var msg=document.getElementById("para");

    function checkusername()
    {
     if(this.value.length<5)
     {
       msg.textContent="username less than 5 characters";
     }
     else
     {
      msg.textContent='';
     }
    }

  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` to set `this` at first parameter and parameters to be used within function body passed at second through N parameters to `.bind()`

```
el.addEventListener('blur',checkusername.bind(el, 5 /*, N */),false);
```

Comment: I have used the event call method that you've suggested above. But still the same problem persists.Here is the complete code with the bind method. Please have a look at the code and point me if there is any mistake in the way I called it.  ` el.addEventListener('blur',checkusername.bind(el, 5),false);

    var msg=document.getElementById("para");

    function checkusername(el,min)
    {
        
        if(el.value.length<min)
        { msg.textContent="username less than 5 characters"; }
        else
        {msg.textContent='';
 } }`     I would love to call a method using bind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
I hope it's will work.

```
<html> 
<body>
<form>
    <label for="text">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <p id="para"></p>
</form>

<script>
    let element=document.getElementById("text");
    element.addEventListener('blur',function(){checkusername(5);},false);

    let msg=document.getElementById("para");

    function checkusername(min)
    {

        if(element.value.length<min)
        {
            msg.textContent="username less than 5 characters";
        }
        else
        {
            msg.textContent='';
        }
    }

</script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: `this.value = [];
        if(this.value.length<min) `                                                                                                       
The above code is setting the text value to empty. And hence the condition will always return false.

Comment: Thank you @Imranpasha, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on the way events are called,I came across two solutions to the above problem.
Have a look at the error message again:-

```
:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property **'length'** of undefined at **checkusername**
```

It is clear from the above message that error is occurring inside the checkusername() function. And the actual error is happening because length is applied on *undefined* variable, in this context,**this**.

The reason for why **this** is undefined in this event call:

1.In regular function call(as shown below), the keyword **this** is associated with the event on which the function is called.

> el.addEventListener('blur',checkusername(),false); //call without parameters

Here,event is calling the function *checkusername()* directly.In short, **this** is holding reference to **el** i.e.., this-->el.
  In this kind of event call, it makes sense to use **length** property on **this** because it is holding something.

2.In the function call that involves passing parameters(problem in the question),the regular function call is not supported as per **JavaScript** standard. JavaScript defines that the function call needs to be embedded inside a anonymous function(as shown below):

> el.addEventListener('blur',function(){checkusername(5);},false); //call with parameters.

Here,event is calling the anonymous function and which in-turn calls the *checkusername().* Hence,**this** does not refer to anything,*undefined*.Therefore, calling *length* on **this** inside *checkusername* returns error.

since, **this** cannot be used, the following techniques are used.

**method 1:**: Passing **el** as part of parameters list.

```
var el=document.getElementById("text");
el.addEventListener('blur',function(){checkusername(el,5);},false);

var msg=document.getElementById("para");

function checkusername(el,min)
{

    if(el.value.length<min)
    {
        msg.textContent="username less than 5 characters";
    }
    else
    {
        msg.textContent='';
    }
}
```

**method 2**: Declaring **el** globally.

```
var el=document.getElementById("text");
    el.addEventListener('blur',function(){checkusername(5);},false);

    var msg=document.getElementById("para");

    function checkusername(min)
    {

        if(el.value.length<min)
        {
            msg.textContent="username less than 5 characters";
        }
        else
        {
            msg.textContent='';
        }
    }
```

Found these solutions in **Javascript&JQuery book by Jon Duckett.**.
[useful link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Hope this was helpful. :) My first answer in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html> 
        <body>
        <form>
            <label for="inputText">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputText" />
            <p id="message"></p>
        </form>

        <script>
            var el=document.getElementById("inputText");
            el.addEventListener('blur',function(){checkusername(5);},false);

            var msg=document.getElementById("message");

            function checkusername (min) {
                if(this.el.value !== (undefined || null) && this.el.value.length < min) {
                    msg.textContent="username less than 5 characters";
                } else {
                    msg.textContent='';
                }
            }

        </script>    
    </body>    
</html>
```